# How can I pass a prop down through all subcomponents without doing so explicitly?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

I am using redux with react to manage the state of a complex form, which will be a single object.  My form will have nested data structures which the user may edit, so for example : Applicant.Address.Country would be updated by a textbox on my form.  I had the idea of making an action called UPDATE_MODEL where updates could be made by passing in objects like :

`{Applicant: {Address: {Country: 'France'} } }`

Which would get merged with the state by the reducer.  The dispatch to update the model would need to be passed down to every single form field, as well as a prop for telling the component where it fits in the entire tree of the form.  Do I have any alternatives to not passing down these two props throughout the form?  It just sounds messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do. You can use React `context`.

Answer (score 2):

React **Context** is specifically meant for this.

This [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) (to ReactJS docs) has a nice example. But this is an experimental feature, so use it with caution.

This [link](http://reactkungfu.com/2016/01/react-context-feature-in-practice/) (to a blog) has a nice summary of when to use it and when not to use it.